# Display primary video for specific ad/property in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a project for ads/properties in Laravel. I have gallery of multiple videos for each individual ad. I want to be able to select one of those videos with radio button and make it primary video for that ad (show that particular video next to ad). I have has many relationship between property and video. I am trying to update my is_main_video column to be 1 if it is main or 0 if it isn't and then display that video if it is 1 in my view. I am having trouble to write that method in my controller I get success message but my is_main_video column remains null. Any help is appreciated. Here are my tables and code.

```
properties (id, title, location, price)

videos (id, filename_video, model_id, is_main_video)
```

In videos table model_id column is foreign key that connects to properties table.

PropertyController.php

```
public function update(StorePropertyInfo $request, Property $property, Video $video)
{
    $videoExtensions = ['mp4', '3gp', 'wmv', 'flv', 'avi'];

    $image_arr = array_filter(explode(',', $request->image), 'strlen');
        foreach ($image_arr as $key => $value) {
            $file = explode('.', $value);
            ext = end($file);

            if (in_array($ext, $videoExtensions)) {

                $query = Property::query();

                if ($request->has('radio')) {
                    $request->get('radio');
                }

                if ($request->radio) {
                    $query->whereHas('videos', function ($query) use ($request) {
                        $query->where('is_main_video', 'like', '%' . $request->radio . '%');
                    });
                }

                $data = $query;

                $video->where('filename_video', $value)
                ->update([
                    'model_id' => $property->id,
                    'is_main_video' => $data
                ]);

            };

        $request->validated();

        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->with('message', 'Property information updated');
        }
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
<input type="hidden" id="hideninput" data-src="property/{{$property->id}}/gallery"value="{{old('video',$video)}}" name="video">
@if (old('video', $video))
    @foreach (array_filter(explode(',',old('video', $video)), 'strlen') as $key =>$value)
        <div id="{{'div_video_'.$key}}" class="col-md-3" style="padding: 15px;">

            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio">Make main 

            <button data="{{$key}}" type="button" class="closebuttonvideo">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>

            <video name="video" id="{{'video_'.$key}}" data={{$value}} src="/storage/property/{{$property->id}}/gallery/{{$value}}" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" data-setup='{"inactivityTimeout": 0}' width="180" height="180"></video>

        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

videos table migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean('is_main_video')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->unique(['model_id', 'is_main_video']);
    });
}
```

Property.php

```
protected $appends = ['is_main_video'];

public function videos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Video::class, 'model_id');
}
```

Video.php

```
public function properties()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Property::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a partial rewrite, something like this:

PropertyController.php in `edit()`; Retrieving a property with attached videos.

```
return view('edit', [
    'property' => Property::with('videos')->find(1),
]);
```

edit.blade.php

```
@foreach($property->videos as $video)
<input type="radio" name="main_video" value="{{ $video->id }}">Video {{ $video->id }}<br>
@endforeach
```

PropertyController.php in `update()`; Toggle the `is_main_video` attribute of each video of the property.

```
foreach ($property->videos as $video) {
    $video->is_main_video = ($video->id == $request->input('main_video'));
    $video->save();
}
```